# How to erase value from vector of struct using erase-remove idiom?

Tags: c++, vector, struct, erase-remove-idiom

How to erase all values from vector of struct, where struct value k equals to 0?

```
struct tabuRecord {
int x;
int y;
int k;
tabuRecord( int x, int y, int k)
    : x(x), y(y), k(k){}
};  

vector <tabuRecord> tabu;

v.insert(v.begin(), tabuRecord(1, 2, 3));
v.insert(v.begin(), tabuRecord(4, 5, 0));
v.insert(v.begin(), tabuRecord(7, 8, 9));
v.insert(v.begin(), tabuRecord(10, 11, 0));
```

I have tried to

```
tabu.erase(std::remove(tabu.begin(), tabu.end(), tabu.k=0), tabu.end());
```

and

```
tabu.erase(std::remove(tabu.begin(), tabu.end(), tabuRecord.k=0), tabu.end());
```

Comment: ... IOW, post a [mcve] please.

Comment: Sorry, I've corrected question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess what you want to do is to remove all objects that have `k==0`, so create a lambda for that:

```
tabu.erase(
    std::remove_if(tabu.begin(), tabu.end(),[](const tabuRecord& t){return t.k == 0;}),
    tabu.end());
```

`std::remove` cannot work because it's not one value that you want to remove, but all values with a specific pattern, which is what `std::remove_if` does.

Answer (score 4):

`std::remove` needs a `tabuRecord` to match against, so you need to do something like.

```
tabuRecord value_to_remove(1,2,3);
tabu.erase(std::remove(tabu.begin(), tabu.end(), value_to_remove), tabu.end());
```

If you want to remove only based on the `k` member, you need to use `std::remove_if` and pass an appropriate function to match for it.

```
auto match_func = [](const tabuRecord& obj) { return obj.k == 2; };
tabu.erase(std::remove_if(tabu.begin(), tabu.end(), match_func), tabu.end());
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
tabu.erase(
    std::remove_if(tabu.begin(), tabu.end(), [valueToErase](const tabuRecord & t) {
    return (t.x==valueToErase.x) && (t.y == valueToErase.y) && (t.k == valueToErase.k);
}), tabu.end());
```

This uses a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) that returns `true` if the three fields are equal, and it removes all values where this is the case.

Here's a full example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    tabuRecord valueToErase(1, 2, 3); // example value to remove

    tabu.push_back({ 1, 2, 3 });
    tabu.push_back({ 4, 5, 6 });
    tabu.push_back({ 1, 2, 3 });
    tabu.push_back({ 7, 8, 9 });

    tabu.erase(
        std::remove_if(tabu.begin(), tabu.end(), [valueToErase](const tabuRecord & t) {
        return (t.x==valueToErase.x) && (t.y == valueToErase.y) && (t.k == 
        valueToErase.k);
    }), tabu.end());

    for (tabuRecord t : tabu) {
        std::cout << "x: " << t.x << " y: " << t.y << " k: " << t.k << std::endl;
    } // print all entries to verify that the correct ones were removed

    return 0;
}
```

Also, there's an error in your construtor, you probably wanted this instead of setting all fields to the same value:

```
: x(x), y(y), k(k) {}
```